# Capture video with overlay data (or watermark)?

Tags: android, video, camera, video-watermarking

I'm creating a video recording app that record video via camera and show some overlay data info (such as current location, weather,... in other word, we can call these as watermark) at the same time.

Currently, i create an overlay layout on top of camera view to display the data info then everything look OK.

But, now is the main part, i want to capture all what we can see on screen (what we can record with camera + all overlay data) to a video. I did try some solutions from tutorials/guide by google such as record screen... but still not success.

Below are some more related questions can be found on Stack Overflow but didn't help me much:

- [Recording video from camera, overlaying bitmaps, adding audio, saving to the device all in as3/AIR mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098420/recording-video-from-camera-overlaying-bitmaps-adding-audio-saving-to-the-dev?rq=1)
- [render overlay graphics into camera video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780968/render-overlay-graphics-into-camera-video)
- [Recording videos with overlay images without using third party library on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036805/recording-videos-with-overlay-images-without-using-third-party-library-on-androi)
- [Android - capture video with watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671525/android-capture-video-with-watermark)

So, did you try to achieve this before? Or anyone can give some hint on how to do it?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: I went with OpenGL for this. You can google "grafika openGL record video".

Comment: @LạngHoàng i have tried ffMpeg but seems to be very slow, can you please shed some light or sample app that you have done, it would really help me.

Comment: @Goofy: As i mentioned above, you can google "grafika openGL record video" for more detail and code. Basic ideal is: create an openGL surface, then draw camera and other things (watermark,..) on it.

Comment: @LạngHoàng, was this grafika openGL record video solution sustainable? Since it's quite old solution I'm a bit scared it to learn about it and use it.

Comment: Hi, to be honest, I don't remember as it was too long time ago. But at that time it worked.